# How can I find the number of concordant/discordant pairs for a given cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: algorithm, google-sheets, statistics, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to figure out the [Kendall's Tau coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) of two different rankings in google sheets, and doing so would require finding the number of concordant and discordant pairs for a given cell.  The number of concordant pairs for a given cell is the number of cells containing a larger number underneath the given cell, and the number of discordant pairs is the amount of smaller numbers beneath the cell.  I am trying to figure out how to write a formula in google sheets (without using the API) that determines the number of concordant or discordant pairs that exist beneath a given cell.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The number of concordant cells for "A1" is given by `=COUNTIF(A2:A20,">"&A1)`, assuming there are 20 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### C2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(IF(A1:A<A2:A, 1, 0))))
```

#### D2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(IF(A1:A>A2:A, 1, 0))))
```

[image: 0]